Is it possible to skip initialization of __main__ module in Python multiprocessing?
It is common in python multiprocessing to use if __name__ == "__main__". However, if I know my child process does not need anything from __main__ module, can I remove this part? e.g.
# test_child.py
from multiprocessing import Process, get_context

def f(x):
    print(f"{x}")

def start():
    ctx = get_context("spawn")
    p = ctx.Process(target=f, args=("hello",))
    p.start()
    p.join()

# test_parent.py
from test_child import start
start()

When I run python test_parent.py , ideally the child process does not need anything from the __main__ module, so it can skil this part, and I don't need to add if __name__ == "__main__" in test_parent.py.
Currently it will cause error though.
Edit: thanks for all the answers. I think one possible way is to use subprocess to run the test_child.py, and do serialization & deserialization manually.

if __name__ == '__main__' is how you skip this.

@user2357112 that requires some change to user-facing code, and I want to avoid it.

Which operating system? On UNIXy systems you can use forking mode to copy your parent process with the imports already done; it's only on Windows where you need each new process started from scratch.

@CharlesDuffy I explicitly use spawn mode here, because I want to make sure some resource management which does not work in fork mode.

I'm curious as to just which kind of "resource management" you're referring to.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

for example, a process with cuda (GPU) resource, is not safe to fork.

"Is it possible to skip initialization of __main__ module in Python multiprocessing?" yes, this is how you use multiprocessing in an interactive REPL. The __main__ module has no __spec__ as it was not loaded by importing, and therefore /spawn.py:prepare won't receive any "init_main_from_name" value. This is also why when it comes time to un-pickle the target function, if the function was defined in the REPL, there's no file to import it from, and it fails, but you can pass an imported function. You cannot avoid this import when executing a file as __main__.

The question that needs to be asked is: When a child process is created, how is the child process's memory initialized?
If the fork method is being used, then the child process inherits a copy of the parent's memory so that its function definitions and global variables are automatically available. Note: technically the child process inherits initially not a copy but the actual memory of the parent process. But when the child process writes to the memory, then a copy of the memory is created and it is into that copy that the write occurs (this is copy on write semantics).
But you are using the spawn method. In this case the child process does not initially inherit the parent's memory. Instead a new Python interpreter is launched into the child process and the interpreter re-reads the input script (test_parent.py in this case) and all executable statements at global scope are executed in order to initialize memory. These executable statements include import statements, function definitions, global variable definitions, etc.
At global scope within test_parent.py we have the executable statement start(). But this will result in recursively creating a new child process which when initialized will again recursively create a new child process ad infinitum. Therefore, any statement at global scope within test_parent.py that creates a child process directly or indirectly (for example, by invoking a function that creates a new child process or importing a module that contains at global scope code that ultimately results in creating a child process) must be excluded from execution during the initialization of the child process. To accomplish this such code is put within an if __name__ == '__main__': block.
The bottom line is you need to place the call to start() within such a special block.

Hi, I know all these stuff. My question is, if I know the child process does not need anything from the parent process, can I avoid the import __main__ stuff in child process, so that I don't need __name__ == '__main__'

Read the last sentence of my answer. You need to place at least the call to start() within test_parent.py in a if __name__ == '__main__': block (better would be also to include the from test_child import start statement also since the child process does not need to re-execute this).

If test_parent.py is imported anywhere, start() will be invoked.
When a subprocess is started, the new interpreter that will run the subprocess imports the main module again and in your case, it leads to the recreation of another subprocess recursively. See Multiprocessing Programming Guidelines. [python.org]
Hence it is essential you protect the “entry point” of the program by using:
if __name__ == '__main__':
  start()
Now the main module’s __name__ is "__main__" only in the main process and not in any other process.

To be clear, I understand the error. And what I want to say is, i know i will never import test_parent , so I want to suppress this error.

What the multiprocessing module does when using spawn context (simplified) is that it calls subprocess.Popen('python -c "connect_to_pipe(some_pipe)"') then it reads the serialized arguments from that pipe, then imports your "main" module then executes your function.
You can write your own new context to replace spawn, then do things differently, (like not importing main), but such solution is not maintainable, and that's why packages like pathos and dask and loky don't do it, they mirror the implementation of the multiprocessing module instead of trying to extend it.
In particular loky does exactly what you need as it skips importing main but may need extra tweaks to the called functions as it will be lacking the needed imports (because it didn't import main). you may need to place some imports inside functions instead of in the global scope, i think the other 2 packages have similar behavior but i am not exactly sure.
A few notable things to worry about are portability to weird platforms and embedding into executables, which such packages don't support.
Eventually you might find you need more control over where and how child processes are created, so you end up creating a client-server architecture with a web API like flask instead of relying on the multiprocessing module, or in the case of embedding you just create a few different executables and call them, or use the subinterpreters API.
